# Is garnish meant to be eaten?

Tags: decorating

Are sprigs of plants decorating meat dishes, or the slice of lemon/olive in drinks meant to be consumed? Are they at least safe to eat?

Comment: Hello Gnubie, and welcome! I'm afraid that health is completely off topic here, see also the on-topic list:http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. I had to remove that part from your question. The etiquette one is in a grey area (is there a universal etiquette of eating?), let's see what the community thinks about it.

Comment: This is a two-pronged question: — 1) Is it proper etiquette for a diner to consume the garnish? — 2) Is it proper etiquette to serve food or drink garnished with items that are not edible?

Comment: @ElmerCat I don't think I'd read this as an etiquette question, more what the culinary intent of the garnish is - is it likely something the chef thinks would taste good with the food, or is it purely visual? (Etiquette is generally off-topic, anyway.)

Comment: There are rules in many countries about what can be used to garnish plates, though... I believe, in the US, garnish must be made out of edible things, so you couldn't use a non-edible flower to garnish a plate or drink (in a restaurant).

Comment: I think it would be better to make this about food safety than about "health"... which I think fits the original intent of the asker.

Comment: I went ahead and edited out the etiquette part - seemed better than having to close it because of that. (I know @rumtscho left that alone, but I think we've pretty clearly established in the past that etiquette is off-topic. See for example http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/820/1672. Talking about presentation from the chef's point of view is fine, but about how to behave at the dinner table is out of scope.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Garnishes should always be edible - there may be laws depending where you are, but in general anything on your plate should be edible or very obviously not meant to be eaten (like a skewer or a paper wrapper). Depending on the specific case, it might not necessarily be meant to be eaten, though. The defining characteristic is the appearance.

Springs of parsley or stronger herbs might not always be too pleasant to eat on their own, so there's nothing wrong with skipping them. I don't think whoever cooked your meal is going to be too upset if you don't like eating sprigs of parsley - but eat them if you want!

With lemon on a glass, you can enjoy the scent as you drink water without actually eating it, or you can squeeze it into the water if you enjoy that little hint of acidity.

So probably the best garnishes are ones that look good *and* are pleasant to eat. For example, a dish sprinkled with something small (finely chopped herbs or cheese or nuts or anything else that's already in the dish). Some garnishes are really all about the appearance, though. You'll have to use your judgment to figure out which is the case for whatever dish is in front of you!

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that whatever is on my plate or in a drink could be consumed and in the case of a Lime, Lemon or Olive garnish in a drink, highly encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Garnishes brighten the plate, give a clue to the flavor of the meal, complement the taste of the dish or fill empty space on the plate.Garnishes aren't just for show. You can eat lemon slices or other citrus garnishes only if they are peeled and can be eaten with a fork.